# call function from address in commandline

Tags: c, gcc

i wrote this code for call function from there address:

```
$ cat main.c 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int test(){
        printf("%s\n","[*] i'm in test");
        return 1;
}

int main(int argc,char **argv){
        int (*m)();
        m=&test;
        printf("[*] test func addr is: %p\n", m);
        (*m)();
        return 0;
}
$ gcc -o main main.c 
$ ./main 
[*] test func addr is: 0x8048414
[*] i'm in test
$
```

no problem

---

but i want run function, and pass there address from `argv` in commandline..

for example if address of function `test()` is `0x222222`, i want after run program with this command `./main 222222`, `test()` function run ..

my code is:

```
$ cat main.c 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int test(){
        printf("%s\n","[*] i'm in test");
        return 1;
}

int main(int argc,char **argv){
        int (*m)();
        long conv ;
        int num;
        num=conv=strtol(argv[1],NULL,10);
        printf("[*] argv[1] is: %d\n", num);
        m=&test;
        printf("[*] test func addr is: %p\n", m);
        m=num;
        (*m)();
        return 0;
}
$ gcc -o main main.c 
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:17:3: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
$ ./main 8048444
[*] argv[1] is: 8048444
[*] test func addr is: 0x8048444
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
$
```

but no run!

Comment: It's `8048444` in hex. You are parsing it as decimal. And otherwise it's a terrible hack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memory addresses are in base 16 not base 10
try changing `strtol(argv[1],NULL,10);` to `strtol(argv[1],NULL,16);`

Answer (score 2):

However, it is true that instead of 10 you should use 16 because addresses are always in hexadecimal format but your code will still run fine even if the argument is 10. Your code is producing **segmentation fault** because of this assignment: `m=num`. This assigns an arbitrary value to m instead of address of test and on calling `(*m)()` a segmentation fault is produced as m is pointing to an invalid location. You should change the last two lines as:

```
num=m;
(*num)();
```

This would run the test function properly.